# Retrieving stock data using xignite api

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have been struggling to get this js script to work.

I keep getting the response that it is "XMLHttpRequest cannot load" "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access."

I have tried adding a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header but then it says one doesn't exist on the requested resource

note: the comments on the page are because this is off another site

any help?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$.ajax({

  // The 'type' property sets the HTTP method.
  // A value of 'PUT' or 'DELETE' will trigger a preflight request.
  type: 'GET',

  // The URL to make the request to.
  url: 'http://globalcurrencies.xignite.com/xGlobalCurrencies.json/GetRealTimeRate?Symbol=EURUSD&_token=28ADDE2CAE3C4F2AB369E9ACDEF214AA',

  Host: '127.0.0.1',
  
  dataType : 'json',

  // The 'contentType' property sets the 'Content-Type' header.
  // The JQuery default for this property is
  // 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', which does not trigger
  // a preflight. If you set this value to anything other than
  // application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain,
  // you will trigger a preflight request.
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

  xhrFields: {
    // The 'xhrFields' property sets additional fields on the XMLHttpRequest.
    // This can be used to set the 'withCredentials' property.
    // Set the value to 'true' if you'd like to pass cookies to the server.
    // If this is enabled, your server must respond with the header
     //Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
   //Access-Control-Allow-origin: true,
    //withCredentials: false
  },

  headers: {
    //Access-Control-Allow-origin: 'http://127.0.0.1',
    // Set any custom headers here.
    // If you set any non-simple headers, your server must include these
    // headers in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' response header.
  },

  success: function() {
    // Here's where you handle a successful response.
    alert( "works" );
  },

  error: function() {
    alert( "failed" );
    // Here's where you handle an error response.
    // Note that if the error was due to a CORS issue,
    // this function will still fire, but there won't be any additional
    // information about the error.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.w3resource.com/JSON/JSONP.php states that due to the "Same Origin Policy" we need to use JSONP to request data from a server residing in a different domain. The above page lists three steps to do POST. To call Xignite, add to your querystring: &_callback=yourFunction (see http://www.xignite.com/Support/FAQ.aspx?faqtype=Topics&faqcat=API_Integration#ka0400000008Rl8AAE).
HTML page with GET should look something like this (for the GlobalQuotes API):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>JSONP example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>

<script>
    var url = "http://globalquotes.xignite.com/v3/xGlobalQuotes.json/GetGlobalDelayedQuotes?Identifiers=avxs,pti,bgne,edit&IdentifierType=Symbol&_Token=28ADDE2CAE3C4F2AB369E9ACDEF214AA&_callback=foo";
    var tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag); 

    function foo(response) {
        debugger;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = response[0].Security.Symbol + ': ' + response[0].Last;
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```